# How do I output multiple values from .map() or use map twice in one iteration?

Tags: rust, functional-programming, iterator

How do I use map twice on one into_iter. Currently I have.

```
let res_arr_to: Vec<String> = v.result.transactions.into_iter().map( |x| x.to).collect();
let res_arr_from: Vec<String> = v.result.transactions.into_iter().map( |x| x.from).collect();
```

What I want is both arrays in one array, the order doesn't matter. I need either a closure that outputs two values (if that is even a closure?). Or a way to use map twice in one iteration, without using the generated value, but instead using the untouched iterator if that makes sense and is possible. I am a total noob in functional programming so if there is a completely different way to do this another explanation is fine to.

v is an EthBlockTxResponse:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct EthTransactionObj {
    from: String,
    to: String

}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct EthTransactions {
    transactions : Vec<EthTransactionObj>
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct EthBlockTxResponse {
    result : EthTransactions
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think what you mean by "use the untouched iterator" is you want to get both values from `x` while only incrementing the iterator once - like a `.peek()` operation. You can actually combine both `to` and `from` values with one `.map()` and produce tuples. But if you want a flat vector with just the `to` and `from` items, `.flat_map()` may be what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the question a bit vague, but think you're trying to get both the `x.to` and the `x.from` at the same time instead of having to iterate the data twice and build two vectors. I'll address that first and then some cases of what you *might* have meant by some other things you mentioned.

One way you can do it is with `.flat_map()`. This will produce one flat vector removing the extra level of nesting. If you wanted tuples, you could just use `.map(|x| (x.from, x.to))`. I'm assuming that `x.from` and `x.to` are `Copy` and you actually want everything in a single vector without nesting.

```rust
let res_arr_combined = v.result.transactions.into_iter()
                                            .flat_map( |x| [x.to, x.from])
                                            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

Reference:

- [Iterator::flat_map()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map)

Excerpt:

> The map adapter is very useful, but only when the closure argument produces values. If it produces an iterator instead, there’s an extra layer of indirection. flat_map() will remove this extra layer on its own.

```rust
fn main()
{
    // Adding more data to an iterator stream.
    (0..5).flat_map(|n| [n, n * n])
          .for_each(|n| print!("{}, ", n));
                  
    println!("");
}
```

output:

```
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9, 4, 16,
```

You may not really require the following, but wrt your comment about wanting to get data from an iterator without using the value or changing the state of the iterator, there is a `.peek()` operation you can invoke on iterators wrapped in `Peekable`.

To get a peekable iterator, you just invoke `.peekable()` on any iterator.

```rust
    let mut p = [1, 2, 3, 4].into_iter().peekable();
    
    println!("{:?}", p.peek());
    println!("{:?}", p.next());
```

output:

```
Some(1)
Some(1)
```

The peekable behaves the same way as the iterator it was taken from, but adds a couple interesting methods like `.next_if(|x| x > 0)`, which produces an iterator that will continue rendering items until the condition evaluates to false without consuming the last item it didn't render.

And one last topic in line with "using map twice in one iteration", if by that you might mean to pull items from a slice in chunks of 2. If `v.result.transactions` is itself a `Vec`, you can use the `.chunks()` method to group its item by 2's - or 3's as I have below:

```rust
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].chunks(3).collect::<Vec<_>>();    
    println!("{:?}", a);
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.unzip()` to collect two vectors at once like this:

```rust
let (res_arr_to, res_arr_from): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = 
    v.result.transactions.into_iter().map(|x| (x.to, x.from)).unzip();
```

Note that into_iter consumes `v.result.transactions` - moving out of that field. This is probably not what you want, and you should copy the strings instead in that case:

```rust
let (res_arr_to, res_arr_from): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = 
    v.result.transactions.iter().map(|x| (x.to.clone(), x.from.clone())).unzip();
```